# Issue when having 2 layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying a simple two horizontal layout that will have the following:

First layout: Profile Image and Profilename and Profile EmaiL
Second Layout: Signout Layout

So I tried the orientation to be horizontal but it is not working properly. I am always getting the following result:

[image]

Value in bottom text should be shown below profile image and profile name layout..

Something like this:

[image]

Here is what I have tried:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@color/redText"
    android:id="@+id/layoutall">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:id="@+id/layoutforBGImage">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/layoutProfileimage"
            android:layout_weight="0.65">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_profile"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:id="@+id/imageforprofile"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/textforprofileLinearLayout"
            android:layout_weight="0.25">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textforprofile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="NAME HERE"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textforprofileemail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="EMAIL ADDRESS"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/layoutforallproduct">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textformoreproducts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="VALUE IN BOTTOM"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What do you think could be a problem here?

Comment: plz post an image of expected layout

Comment: Your first three LinearLayouts do not have an orientation

Comment: @Sanjana You mentioned you need two horizontal layouts but you want the "value in bottom" layout to be below the other layout? Please mention what is the exact requirement. M assuming value in bottom is the signout layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont setted orientation of root layout
do like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@color/redText"
    android:id="@+id/layoutall"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:id="@+id/layoutforBGImage"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/layoutProfileimage"
            android:layout_weight="0.65">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_profile"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:id="@+id/imageforprofile"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/textforprofileLinearLayout"
            android:layout_weight="0.25">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textforprofile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="NAME HERE"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textforprofileemail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="EMAIL ADDRESS"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/layoutforallproduct">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textformoreproducts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="VALUE IN BOTTOM"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out you just need to set **orientation** in main layout and **width** to **match parent** if you need bottom text to be in bottom

Add `android:orientation="vertical"` in main linear layout

And change `android:layout_width="0dp"` to `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

**CODE**

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/redText"
    android:id="@+id/layoutall">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:id="@+id/layoutforBGImage">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/layoutProfileimage"
            android:layout_weight="0.65">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_profile"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:id="@+id/imageforprofile"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/textforprofileLinearLayout"
            android:layout_weight="0.25">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textforprofile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="NAME HERE"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textforprofileemail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="EMAIL ADDRESS"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/layoutforallproduct">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textformoreproducts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="VALUE IN BOTTOM"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you explain the answer rather than a code dump, please?

Comment: Thanks. The orientation was what I thought the problem was, but wanted to be sure that was all you added

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `android:orientation="vertical"` to parent layout because you want that layout below upper layout having taxt and imageview, as now you use **orientation="vertical"** you have to change `android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"` and make **imageview** to 
`android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"` so that it will be easy to maintain in all devices with different resolutions.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layoutall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@color/redText"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutforBGImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.50">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutProfileimage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageforprofile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_profile" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/textforprofileLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textforprofile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="NAME HERE"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textforprofileemail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="EMAIL ADDRESS"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutforallproduct"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textformoreproducts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="VALUE IN BOTTOM"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add **android:orientation="vertical"** in main linear layout
And change **android:layout_width="0dp"** to **android:layout_width="match_parent"** and add **android:gravity="left"** to **Textview**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:id="@+id/layoutall">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:id="@+id/layoutforBGImage">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/layoutProfileimage"
            android:layout_weight="0.65">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_profile"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:id="@+id/imageforprofile"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/textforprofileLinearLayout"
            android:layout_weight="0.25">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textforprofile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="NAME HERE"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textforprofileemail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="EMAIL ADDRESS"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/layoutforallproduct">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textformoreproducts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="VALUE IN BOTTOM"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```